# Are $\mathbb C[x , y]$ and $ \frac {\mathbb R[x , y]}{ \left<x^2+1 , y\right>}$ PIDs?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

> Are $\mathbb C[x , y]$ and $ \frac {\mathbb R[x , y]}{ \left<x^2+1 , y\right>}$ PIDs?

Can anyone please educate me how to handle two variable stuff?

I know how to check this kind of stuff in one variable.

Comment: $$A[x,y]=A[x][y]$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hints** : if $R$ is an integral domain, can $(X,Y)$ be principal in $R[X,Y]$ ?

And $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+1) \simeq \mathbb{C}[Y]$

Comment: I did not get you. Can you please elaborate? I have no   idea about handling these stuffs in two variable. Can you please educate me how to handle them?@Max

Comment: For the second point, do you know how to show that $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1) \cong \mathbb C$?  It follows somewhat straightforwardly from there

Comment: I just gave you hints. What point would you like me to elaborate ?

Comment: second line@Max

Comment: I do not know how to show that..@D_S

Comment: $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1) \cong \mathbb C$ is a definition of $\mathbb C$, is it not?

Comment: But how @Ennar I can 't understand

Comment: @INDIAN, well, how do you define $\mathbb C$?

Comment: $\mathbb C$ contains $a+ci$ where a and c are real numbers@Ennar

Comment: @INDIAN, that's not really a definition, but, oh, well. The appropriate definition you are looking for is that $\mathbb C$ is a two-dimensional real vector space $\mathbb R^2$ with ring structure defined as $(a,b)\cdot (a',b') = (aa' - bb', ab' + a'b)$. Then the linear embedding $\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$ given by $a\mapsto (a,0)$ is a ring homomorphism, so we consider $\mathbb R$ to be subring of $\mathbb C$, and we write $1$ instead of $(1,0)$. We also write $i$ instead of $(0,1)$. Since $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is a base for $\mathbb R^2$, it follows that every complex number is of the form $a+bi$.

Comment: To show that this $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)$, consider evaluation homomorphism $R[X]\to\mathbb C$ given by $1\mapsto 1$, $X\mapsto i$ and show that its kernel is $(X^2+1)$. Use the first isomorphism theorem to get the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*

1. $\mathbb C[x , y] \cong \mathbb C[x][y]$. Now use that $D[y]$ is a PID iff $D$ is a field.
2. $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+1,y) \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$

Comment: How did you write this. What does $\mathbb C[x][y]$ mean?

Comment: @INDIAN, the same thing as $R[y]$ for the ring $R=\mathbb C[x]$.

Comment: how would u define $\frac{\mathbb R[x,y,z]} {[x,y]}$?@Ennar

Comment: @INDIAN, I'm not sure what you wrote there. Anyway, you should probably consult your lecture notes before asking questions. MSE isn't a substitute for lectures and studying.

Comment: Actually I wanted to understand $\frac {\mathbb R[x,y] }{(x^2+1 , y)}$ Can you please tell me what is it? How is it defined?@Ennar

Comment: what $<x^2+1 , y>$ stand for? What does that mean?@Ennar